# removing characters till a specific substring

Tags: batch-file

I have a string like ' ntuser.dat ntuser.dat.log ntuser.ini test.bat test1.bat advice.20131024.98767 textdoc.txt'
I would like to remove all characters from the specified string till 'advice.20131024'
How can i do this using windows batch commands?
I also need to save the result string in a variable
thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to remove the bits after that `advice.20131024` too?

Comment: yes, all characters before advice.20131024. The advice.20131024 can be at any arbitrary location in the given string.

Comment: but you want to keep the stuff afterwards correct?

Comment: yeah, the stuff after that is needed

Answer (score 4):

This sets the string,
changes it to delete everything up until the end of `advice` and replace it with `advice`
then echoes the rest of the string.

```
set "string=ntuser.dat ntuser.dat.log ntuser.ini test.bat test1.bat advice.20131024.98767 textdoc.txt"
set "string=%string:*advice=advice%"
echo "%string%"
```

Answer (score 1):

(a) Searching in string

```
    set text=ntuser.dat ntuser.dat.log ntuser.ini test.bat test1.bat advice.20131024.98767 textdoc.txt

:loop
    if "%text:~0,6%"=="advice" goto exitLoop
    set text=%text:~1%
    goto loop

:exitLoop
    echo %text%
```

(b) with for loop

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    set text=ntuser.dat ntuser.dat.log ntuser.ini test.bat test1.bat advice.20131024.98767 textdoc.txt
    set result=

    for %%f in (%text%) do (
        set x=%%f
        if "!x:~0,6!"=="advice" (
            set result=%%f
        ) else (
            if not "!result!"=="" set result=!result! %%f
        )
    )

    echo %result%
```

(c) See foxidrive answer (i always forget that)

Comment: Can the '.20131024' part after 'advice' also be kept in the check? Because there can be more than one substrings starting with 'advice' in the given string

Comment: If you know that value, adjust comparision string and length of the substring. In both examples you will need to change `:~0,6%` to `:~0,15%`

Comment: the part after 'advice.' is actually the current date. So i am getting it and storing it in another variable. How to add that variable to the comparison?

Comment: Exactly what is what you need? First advice and date, all advice and date, all advice of a particular date, ...